# Visual studio building 2 applications (Test and Live)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

The result required: 2 applications (windows / windows 8 store app) (One prefixed with TEST)

I am coming from a Windows 8 store development And a few other web / desktop(windows) developments and wanted to know whats the best way to create 2 applications with VS. (2010 / 2012)

The idea is that the 2 applications have different names (which is controlled in the Project properties, app manifest, etc)
From VS2012 I could create another project, and have it linked to the existing files. (Which means every time i add a new class i need to add the link to the other side too).

Questions i'm looking for
What are the methods out there that people are using? 
Could someone point me to some resources regarding this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi John, I am trying to create a secondary application which can be used for testing. This is a LOB application, so I need a second app which connects to a TEST system. (Exactly the same code base, but with a different name). I think i am sure that Windows 8 apps handles the name using the package.appmanifest file.

Comment: I don't know about Windows Store applications, but for every other kind of application, this would be done by having one application with two configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem for now with the following steps

1. Created package.LIVE.appxmanifest file
   You can specify a different name for the app here.
2. Creating a copy of the Project file, i.e. the .csproj file
   This is still using the original pacakge.appxmanifest file
3. Update the properties on the package.LIVE.appxmanifest
   Set the values: BuildAction = AppxManifest
   Also update the properties of the package.appxmanifest file (In the LIVE project) to
   BuildAction = None
   NOTE: Do this choosing the file under the LIVE project

Now build the corresponding projects and you should be good to go.

The drawbacks so far are that each time I add a file i need to add them to each of the other projects i have added. Any changes to the package.appxmanifest file, like changing the logo, the capabilities etc, need to be changed in the other appxManifest files too.